# Generic list print method

Tags: java, list, generics

I am trying to write a generic print method that works for all classes that implements the "Iterable" interface

```
public class List<T> {

    public static <T extends Iterable<T>> void print(T[] list){
        for (Object element : list){
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList();
        l.add(1);
        l.add(5);
        l.add(3);
        l.add(2);
        print(l);
    }
}
```

but I receive the error "The method print(T[]) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList)"

Comment: You probably don't want to name your class `List`. Also, the `T` in `class List<T>` is not the same as the `T` in `public static <T extends Iterable<T>> void print(T[] list)`.

Answer (score 7):

Your parameter is `T[]`. Which is an array of a type that extends `Iterable`. You simply want `T`. But you also need a type variable for the type parameter in `Iterable`. You need

```
public static <T extends Iterable<E>, E> void print(T list) {
```

You need this because you don't want an `Iterable<ArrayList>` which is what it is in your current implementation.

Comment: I think `print(Iterable<?>)` would be fine too unless I read too fast.

Comment: @PaulBellora Yeah, you're right. That works too (and probably better in this case). It's fun to play with generics.

Answer (score 4):

Your generic definition isn't correct. You're trying to set the boundaries to `<T extends Iterable<T>>` but the generic parameter (`Integer`) is not the `T`.

You can get it working by introducing a separate generic parameter: one to indicate the collection and one to indicate the collection's values.

Sidenote: You don't need `T[]` at all. You just want `T`.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add(1);
        l.add(5);
        l.add(3);
        l.add(2);
        print(l);
    }

    public static <S, T extends Iterable<S>> void print(T list){
        for (Object element : list){
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
1
5
3
2
```

Answer (score 3):

As `System.out.println` accepts all `Object`s, and you're not really using your generics inside the method, I see no reason to use generics at all. This code will accomplish the same thing:

```
public static void print(Iterable<?> list) {
    for (Object element : list) {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
}
```

---

## What you have done

I also want to add that you are confusing the `T[]` quite a bit. `T[]` means "*an **array** of type T*". But you're trying to pass it an *`ArrayList`*, which is not the same as an *array* (The class `ArrayList` uses regular arrays internally, but that's irrelevant).

Let's take a look at your original method declaration:

```
public static <T extends Iterable<T>> void print(T[] list) {
    for (Object element : list) {
        System.out.println(element);
    }
}
```

This method is declared to accept a parameter that is: An array of a generic type T, where the generic type T is Iterable over the generic type T.

Let's read that last part again: *where the generic type T is Iterable over the generic type T.*

That is, the generic type should be iterable over itself.

You would need a class like this to use your current `print` method:

```
class MyClass implements Iterable<MyClass> {
    ...
}
```

And then use your print method like this:

```
MyClass[] objects = new MyClass[5];
print(objects);
```

However, with your current print method it would only call the `MyClass.toString` method for each of the 5 elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

If `T` extends `Iterable` then just do this:

```
public static <E, T extends Iterable<E>> void print(T list){
        for (Object element : list){
            System.out.println(element);
        }
}
```

Edit: what you had declared was `T extends Iterable<T>` which could for instance be Iterable, which is probably not what you're trying to achieve. Then just add another type of the elements of the list.

If you don't specifically work with the type then you can also declare the generic type as:

```
<T extends Iterable<?>>
```

Comment: It won't compile either.

Comment: Yeah I am just looking more closely at his generic definition which isn't probably right..